# Mouse scrolling issue in a specific section in pagepiling.js

Tags: html, css, scroll, pagepiling.js

While scrolling a specific area that will scroll the entire section. overflow scroll section not working properly.

```
.scroll_sec {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto ;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Please check the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBzyrz

Comment: I would encourage you to make use of the fullPage.js library instead, is big brother. You can then use the [Parallax extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html) to emulate the pagePiling.js behaviour as detailed [here on this post](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/how-create-tumblr-website-effect/). Then you'll be able to enjoy from all fullpage.js features ,including responsive options and turnf Off the piling effect.

Comment: @Alvaro I have already done the website in pagepiling.js, and fullpage.js also have the same issue https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxzxEr, please try to scroll the black background section in the first slide. Is this possible to solve the issue in pagepiling.js.

Comment: Nop, it doesn't have it. You can use the option `normalScrollElements` to solve it. Also, you should be using fullPage.js version 3, not version 2 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer to this question.

There is an option for `normalScrollElements` in pagepiling.js. We can mention the class or id of the overflow scroll section.

Please check the code from here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBRpKa